# Intentionally closing a connection to image in docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, redis, redis-cluster

I have a redis cluster deployed using docker-compose.yml. It has 3 masters and 1 replica for each master. I also have services `client` and `storage`, where `storage` works with my redis cluster. All of my services are connected via a `network` with the following configuration:

```
networks:
  my-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

the example of my redis-node:

```
redis-node:
  image: redis
  networks:
    my-network:
      ipv4_address: 172.28.x.y
  ports:
    - 7000:7000
    - 17000: 17000
```

I'd like to be able to replicate a crash scenario where the network is gone and my `storage` appears in a network where only one redis-master node is available and all the other ones are isolated.

My first solution was to create a different network used for isolation but then I can't configure the ports the right way.

Is there any way to resolve the problem? Does docker-compose have this kind of feature?

Comment: You usually can't delete a Docker network while there are containers still attached to it, so the scenario you describe doesn't really make sense.  (I'd consider deleting all of the `networks:` blocks you show, too: Docker can manage IP address assignment on its own, and Compose will provide a `default` network for you.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't want to delete a network, I want to be able to simulate a situation where the network is isolated. And the `networks` block is needed in my case, as it's one of the requirements to have a non-default network configured.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such method, however, you could use an iptables to achieve the same goal.

To block the client, try the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
iptables -I INPUT -s IP -j DROP
```

To unblock:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
iptables -D INPUT -s IP -j DROP
```